# Linked list insertion results in sysmalloc assertion error

Tags: c

I have written a code to add a new member to a list . Its working fine when I take add two members. However, as soon as I add third and compile and run the code gives me an error. The code and error are as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list_no {
struct list_no *prev,*nest;
struct linked_list *fnl;
int seq_no;
};
static int counter = 0;

struct list_no *lists,*first;

int add_list()
{
   struct list_no *temp;

    counter++;
    if(lists == '\0')
    {
         lists = (struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct list_no));
         lists->prev = '\0';
         lists->nest = '\0';
         lists->fnl  = '\0';
         lists->seq_no = 1;
         first = lists;
    }
    else
    {
         temp = lists;
         lists->nest = (struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
         lists = lists->nest;
         lists->fnl = '\0';
         lists->prev = temp;
         lists->nest = NULL;
         lists->seq_no = counter;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   int i=0,lcount;
   int i=0,lcount;

   char ch = 'y';
   first = '\0';
   lists = first;
   int w;

   while(i != 3)
   {
       add_list();
       printf("\n the val ::%d\n",lists->seq_no);
       i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

the error message coming after ./a.out is :

```
the val ::1
the val ::2

a.out: malloc.c:3097: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Why its not able to add third member?

Comment: This is what a debugger is for.

Comment: What about a proper subject?!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth hi its code looks fine.... could you give me any suggestions what might be wrong

Comment: @ezdazuzena     what subject ? i didnt get you.......

Comment: @karan2386: Look at the title ;) Someone already fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your pointer

```
  temp = lists;
  lists->nest = (struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
  lists = lists->nest;
```

So `temp` points to the same memory as `lists`. Then you allocate memory for `lists->neste`. And after that, you let `lists` point to that memory, which means, also `temp` points to it.

Try

```
memcpy((void*)temp, (*void) lists, sizeof(lists));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `malloc` uses `sizeof(struct linked_list)`, should be `sizeof(struct linked_no)`.
I guess this struct is smaller than `list_no`,.so when writing you corrupt memory.
On the third allocation, `malloc` sees the corruption and gets upset.

Some other points:

1. "next" should be spelled with "x", not "nest".
2. Pointers should be initialized with `NULL`, not `'\0'` (ends up the same, but `NULL` is the correct type).
3. You should try to remove the duplication of entry allocation and initialization (first time and following time). Your main bug is partly a result of this duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems stand out:

1) The following:

```
lists->nest = (struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
```

should use `sizeof(struct list_no)` and not `sizeof(struct linked_list)`. This is probably what's causing the immediate problem.

2) Let's say your list contains two elements. Now consider the following line:

```
  lists->nest = (struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
```

Whatever value `lists->nest` had before the above got executed is now irrevocably lost. You've leaked memory and have lost part of your list.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second case you do:

```
(struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
```

which probably allocates not enough memory because it only allocates enough memory for a `linked_list` struct and not `list_no`. You want to do:

```
(struct list_no *)malloc(sizeof(struct list_no));
```

Also: casting the return result of `malloc` is unnecessary and just adds clutter and instead of `'\0'` you should use `NULL` as it makes the code a bit easier to read.